# how to make proceeding bar in music player?(gui)

Tags: java, swing, slider

im making a gui music player. In other music players, there is proceeding bar that shows how many the music plays. and i want to adjust the proceeding bar's button as the music plays
proceeding bar is like sound adjusting slider. 
how to make proceeding bar?

Comment: Use `JProgressBar`. If you want to make it so the user can click on the bar to jump to a particular point in the track, add a `MouseListener` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using progress bar, here the java doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

See the "How to Use Progress Monitors" section, may be it is more appropriate for your requirement.